# помогите пожалуйста выдает ошибку " b[i] = str(b[i[0: 9]]) TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python

```py
st = input("Введите строку из нескольких слов, разделённых пробелами:__")
a = 1
b = st.split(" ")
for i in range(len(b)):
    if len(b[i]) > 10:
        b[i] = b[i[0: 9]]
    print(f"{a} - {b[i]}")
    a += 1
```

Пользователь вводит строку из нескольких слов, разделённых пробелами.
Вывести каждое слово с новой строки.
Строки необходимо пронумеровать.
Если в слово длинное, выводить только первые 10 букв в слове.

Comment: Ошибка по скобкам *b[i]* - Элемент *i* -индекс, срез берется у элемента (списка), а не у индекса `b[i][:9]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему уже указали - неправильная индексация. Можно написать совсем без индексации ([enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)). И слова обрабатывать срезами не обязательно, f-строки умеют форматировать их правильно:

```
s = input("Введите строку из нескольких слов, разделённых пробелами:__")
for i, w in enumerate(s.split(), start=1):
    print(f'{i} - {w:.10}')
```

> ```
> $ python words.py
> Введите строку из нескольких слов, разделённых пробелами:__11111111111111111111 222 333
> 1 - 1111111111
> 2 - 222
> 3 - 333
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Ваша ошибка была в это строке `b[i] = b[i[0: 9]]`. Вы пытаетесь сделать срез индекса `i[0: 9]`, а это целочисленное значение срез по которому невозможен, вот интерпретатор и ругается. Можно было так `b[i][:10]`. (конечный индекс не включительно)

Вот немного улучшенная версия вашего кода:

```
string = input("Введите строку из нескольких слов, разделённых пробелами:__")
counter = 1
splitted = string.split()
for word in splitted:
    if len(word) > 10:
        print(f"{counter} - {word[:10]}")
    else:
        print(f"{counter} - {word}")
    counter += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Я нашел решение нужно немного видоизменить 6 строчку

```
    b[i] = b[i][: 10]
```